# Example of Exponential Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a definition below (source: On Hedetniemi's Conjecture and the color template scheme by C. Tardiff and X Zhu): 
The exponential graph $G^H$ has all the functions from vertex-set of $H$ to that of $G$ as vertices and two of these functions $f,g$ are joined by an edge if $[f(u),g(v) ∈ E(G)]$ for all $[u,v] ∈ E(H)$.
Can anyone give me an example of exponential graph based on that definition?
Thank you.

Comment: These graphs get huge very quickly. The smallest example that is not entirely trivial needs $3^3=27$ elements (so that both $G$ and $H$ can have 2 vertices that are connected and 2 vertices that are not connected). If you understand the definition you should be able to create an example yourself.

Comment: @Leen Droogendijk: Thank you for your comment. The problem is that I don't really understand the definition very well. I am still unsure, what are the vertices of $G^H$ ? Are they functions? Also, what are vertices of $G$ ? Should they be mappings of vertices of $H$ ? I have graph G whose vertex set is {u1,u2,u3} and edge set is {[u1,u2],[u2,u3]} and graph H which is a complete graph with n=3, then what is the exponential graph $G^H$ ? What kinds of functions should I define first here? Please help me, thank you

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk : Ah, I want to edit my comment before about the example of graph $G$ and $H$. My real question: If I have graph G which is a complete graph with $n=4$ <br/> and graph H which is a Caley graph Cay ($Z8$,{-2,-1,1,2}), that is a graph whose vertices are integers modulo 8 and edges are $[u,v]$ if $u-v$ element {-2,-1,1,2}, <br/> then what is the exponential graph $G^H$ ? <br/> Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I'll try to give a very small example with some explanation.
As soon as you understand the definition you should be able to do larger examples by yourself.
The vertices of $G^H$ are indeed functions.
They are independent of the graph structure of $G$ and $H$, they only depend on their vertex sets.
So let $G=\{0,1\}$, $H=\{a,b\}$. (I choose different sets hoping to make things clearer.)
There are four possible functions $H\to G$.

$f_0$ maps everything to 0, $f_1$ maps everything to 1, $g$ maps $a\to 0,b\to 1$
and $h$ maps $a\to 1,b\to 0$.
So our graph $G^H$ has these four functions as vertices.

Now for the edges we do need the graph structure of both $G$ and $H$.
So let us assume $G$ has only the edge $[0,1]$ and $H$ has only the edge $[a,b]$.
As an example let's ask ourselves if $[f_0,f_1]$ is an edge.
Since $H$ has only edge $[a,b]$ we just need to check if $[f_0(a),f_1(b)]=[0,1]$ is an edge of $G$,
which is true.
(Note that if you work with simple graphs, then $[b,a]$ is the same edge, but
$[f(b),g(a)]$ will generally be different from $[f(a),g(b)]$).
Now you have to do the adjacency check for all possible pairs.
How many pairs you need to check depends on whether you are talking about simple graphs or digraphs,
and whether or not you want to consider loops.

Regarding the question in your comment: in this case the result graph has 65536 vertices,
so the question "what does it look like" will not be adequately answered by providing an incidence matrix.
You may be looking for a statement like: this is isomorphic to $<$some famous graph$>$, but the argument below makes this improbable.

Another way of telling "what does it look like" may be to note that the vertices of $G^H$ are exactly the 8-digit numbers in base 4 and then characterize when two of those numbers are adjacent.
Because all vertices in the complete graph are adjacent but there are no loops (I assume),
our edge condition will be that $p_0\ldots p_7$ is adjacent to $q_0\ldots q_7$ if
and only if $p_i$ is different from $q_{i+1},q_{i+2},q_{i+6}$ and $q_{i+7}$ for all $i$,
where the $p_i$ and $q_i$ are base-4 digits and the indices are taken modulo 8.

Note that this graph has isolated points. $01123333$ will be an isolated point, since (taking $i=2$)
no base-4 digit can be different from $0,1,2$ and 3.
So our graph probably will not be isomorphic to some "famous" graph, since those tend to be connected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, from the example you give, you say that $[f_0(a),f_1(b)]=[0,0]$, shouldn't it be $[f_0(a),f_1(b)]=[0,1]$ and thus $[f_0,f_1]$ is an edge in $G^H$ ?

Comment: Also, you mentioned that "How many pairs you need to check depends on whether you are talking about simple graphs or digraphs, and whether or not you want to consider loops." Now, say that I want to consider loops, then I have to check whether $[f_0,f_0],[f_1,f_1],[g,g],[h,h]$ are edges in $G^H$, right?

Comment: As for simple graphs or digraphs, I choose simple graphs. You also said that $[b,a]$ is the same edge as $[a,b]$, but $[f(b),g(a)]$ will generally be different from $[f(a),g(b)]$. I understand this, but, there will be 2 versions of $G^H$ then, is that right? I have checked if I use $[a,b]$ as the edge of $H$, the edge of $G^H$ will be $[f_0,f_1],[f_0,g],[f_1,h],[g,g],[h,h]$. And when I use [b,a], then the edge of $G^H$ will be $[f_0,f_1],[f_0,h],[f_1,g],[g,g],[h,h]$. Which one should I choose then? Or are they both the correct $G^H$ ? Sorry I keep asking questions, and thank you

Comment: First question (about $f_1(b)$): you are absolutely right.

Second question (about loops): that's part of it.
The other part is, that loops in $H$ give you more restrictions and loops in $G$ give you less restrictions,
about what edges will be in $G^H$.
E.g. if $G$ is a complete graph with loops at all its vertices then $G^H$ is a complete graph as well
(and this is not the case when $G$ is a complete graph without loops).

Comment: Third question (about simple graphs versus digraphs): no, both $[a,b]$ and $[b,a]$ are edges of $H$,
even though they are the same, so according to the definition both $[f(a),g(b)]$ and $[f(b),g(a)]$
must be in $E(G)$ before $f$ and $g$ can be adjacent.

Comment: First question is solved. For second question, thank you for explaining. So, as for your example, all possible functions that can be vertices in GH are $[f_0,f_0],[f_1,f_1],[g,g],[h,h],[f_0,f_1],[f_0,g],[f_0,h],[f_1,g],[f_1,h],[g,h]‌​$. Is that all? Regarding the third question: So the edges in $G^H$ are $[f_0,f_1],[g,g],[h,h]$ only? That would be disconnected graph, wouldn't that?

Comment: You have proven that you understand how to test for adjacency by pointing out the error I made
and that was the only purpose of the example.
I trust you on the other calculations and if you slipped on one of them it does not matter either.
"all possible functions that can be vertices in GH" should be phrased as
"all possible function pairs that can be edges in $G^H$".

Comment: Ah, yeah, thank you for pointing out that my error. You do a great help to me. As for my last question, I would make a summary: It doesn't matter that $G$ and $H$ are connected graphs, the exponential graph $G^H$ can be disconnected graph. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely. The answer to your "real question" explicitly mentions (in the last paragraph) that the result graph has isolated points, and you know that both constituents are connected.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your help. Your explanation helps me doing my final paper.